# How to POST Data to server and Get Response?With intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I Followed [this](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64) to POST data to Server and Get Response

Here I am Passing Data through Intent the Below intent I used In Main activity

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, Mydata.class);
            i.putExtra("data", data);
            startActivity(i);
```

For Receiving Intent I used this

```
Intent i = getIntent();
        String data = i.getExtras().getString("data");
```

Here Data Is Not passing to URL..

This is My Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Sdata extends Activity {

    TextView content;
    String utext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        content    =   (TextView)findViewById( R.id.content );

        try{

            GetData();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            content.setText(" url exeption! " );
        }

    }

    public void GetData()
    {

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String data = i.getExtras().getString("data");

        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        try
        {
            utext="http://google.com/api/?" + data;
            URL url = new URL("utext");


            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            text = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                reader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }

        content.setText(text);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text5)).setText(utext);

    }

}
```

After this I need to Get Response from Server like

```
"Username  Login Success"
"Username  Logout Success"
or "Invalid User"
```

**Update:**

Here I am Not using any JSON data or JSONstring and My data is

```
String data = "userid" + "=" + userid;
            data += "&" + "phone" + "=" + phone;
            data += "&" + "device" + "=" + device;
            data += "&" + "clock_time" + "=" + "00:00:00";
            data += "&" + "clock_date" + "=" + clock_date;
```

Can any one suggest me....

Comment: Why is Php mentioned? I don't see Php code.

Comment: Here My serveris PHP... Check the Example...link I have Given

Comment: You should try using jsoup it makes this stuff a lot easier and works well on android and why not do the post and get on the second activity and send the user back to main activity if its the wrong login ?

Comment: can you post ur answer or Reference link @Amroelaswar

Comment: @Don'tBenegative ok sure but I think your problem here could be that you are running that on the main thread, internet connections should be run in a seperate thread that could be causing the problem

Comment: @Don'tBenegative are you running the connection on a seperate thread ?

Comment: actually I tried with both... But not working.. Is there Any other POST method... with this Intent data..

Comment: actually i am using the json string and same way i am posting to the server but it is working for me

Comment: Sir Can you Update Ur Code in my Code... and Also for UTF 8 shall I need to sapaerately add for each part of data... or Complete data

Answer (score 0):

You can refer something like below, and you should work with server side too.

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String mUrl = "https://url";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(mUrl);
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("data", "data");
        object.put("data2", "data2");
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(object.toString(),"UTF-8");
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if (response != null) {
            result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        }
```

Comment: is there any way to work with above URl I mean my My url here In "data" I am getting a lot of strings... concated

Comment: DefaultHttpClient is deprecated in api-22, and removed in api-23.

Comment: Ho Ok is there any complete tutorial for your code,,.. I am new to android or else can you Update ur answer with my code...

Comment: I think No its Not Wrong.. itried with direct URL also... may be @DanielNugent said that DefaultHttpClient is deprecated in api-22,23

Answer (score 0):

try using jsoup and doing something like this

```
Handler loginhandler;
TextView yourTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextviewid);

    //here you create a handler to which you will be sending messages from the thread
    loginhandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (""+msg.obj == "Logged in"){
                    //if the user logged in successfully then you take him to the next activity
                    Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourNextActivity.class);
                    startActivity(startIntent);
                    finish();
            }
            yourTextView.setText(""+msg.obj);
        }
    };

    //here you create an instance of the thread class you created further down and you start it 

    Thread loginThread = new Thread(new loginThread());
    loginThread.start();


}

//your method that gets and posts data to internet that you will call from the thread
public String getData(){


    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("Yourserver/login.php")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

    Connection.Response dataPage = Jsoup.connect("yourserver/login.php")
            .data("_username", "Users login")
            .data("_password", "users password")
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .execute();

    Document ParsedDataPage = dataPage.parse();
    Element pageLoginStatus = ParsedDataPage.select("div.login-status").get(0);
    String dataToReturn = Jsoup.parse(""+pageLoginStatus).text();
    return dataToReturn;
}

//here you create your thread in a class that implements Runnable and you put inside the run() method what you want it to do 
private class loginThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String myData = getData();

            //here you create a message and send it to your handler that you created above
            Message message = Message.obtain();
            message.obj = myData;
            loginhandler.sendMessage(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //Do something with the exception here   
        }
    }
}
```

Ok I basically wrote you the whole code now you just have to do some modifications to the .data() that you send to the server depending on the data you want to send you should take a look on html code of the website for that and then all you have to do is put this code in your class that implements Activity. You also have to download the Jsoup library and put it in your external libraries folder.

You should probably watch a tutorial on how threads work because you will be using them a lot if you plan to do internet stuff on Android.

Comment: sir I am new to android Can you Update your code I my code.. your code is fine but not working with my  code'

Comment: @Don'tBenegative I edited the code but you should probably read some doc about threads and work a bit with Jsoup before using it in Android what I do is Write my java code in eclipse to make sure everything works good then I copy the methods to my Android app

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a separate method to post the date to the server here is the example code ... you can refer it.

```
public String postData(String sURL,String sData)
    {
        try
        {
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("jsonString", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(sData, "UTF-8"); 
            URL url = new URL(sURL);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
            wr.write( data ); 
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                       sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            System.out.println("POST Respon "+sb.toString());  
            return sb.toString();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: here what is surl... or where is URL Here I am not using any JSON string

Comment: @hemanth1087 can you update your answer in my complete code ... I am new to android I tried ur code But its not working... Here I am getting data Through a Intent Where should I need to Use it...